# What does Tonks do when Lupin turns into a werewolf?

Tags: harry-potter, werewolf

Does she leave the house every month when there's a full moon, or is Lupin able to control himself and not attack her and their child?

Comment: She goes out with the gals.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - If their cycles are synched, that might be for the best anyway...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

#### Once he takes Wolfsbane Potion, he'd be no danger to her.

When Lupin takes his Wolfsbane Potion, it makes him not a danger to others. It lets him keep his mind, and while he was at Hogwarts, he'd be able to curl up in his office and wait until it was over.

> “The Potion that Professor Snape has been making for me is a very recent discovery. It makes me safe, you see. As long as I take it in the week preceding the full moon, I keep my mind when I transform … I am able to curl up in my office, a harmless wolf, and wait for the moon to wane again.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 18 (Moony, Wormtail, Padfoot and Prongs)*</sup></sub>

He'd be able to do something similar while living with Tonks. He could go into a spare room and wait out his transformation the same way he did at Hogwarts. He'd still have his mind, so he wouldn't try to escape and eat Tonks, or end up destroying the house.

Comment: Yes, but Lupin said he was never much of a potion maker which is why Snape had to make it for him.  Did Snape continue to make it for him after PoA?

Comment: @Bishop I'm sure he could find a suitable apothecary that would sell it to him. He wouldn't even have to buy in secret since he was outed in PoA.

Comment: @TBear Yes, but the potion is described as being very expensive and elaborate, and Lupin lost his main source of income when he left Hogwarts. I doubt he'd have the funds to buy the Wolfsbane Potion. Anyway, potions aren't usually sold pre-made in the wizarding world; the ingredients are sold seperately and people are expected to make their potions themselves.

Comment: @TheDarkLord, where is it described as *expensive*?  Difficult, yes; expensive, I don't recall that.

Comment: @Wildcard Difficult tends to imply expensive. It means that there aren't that many people who can make it, so those who can have a lot of leeway in how much they can afford to ask.

Comment: Also worth noting, Tonks is an auror, she'd be pretty darned good at potions.

Comment: @Wildcard In [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/remus-lupin) the ingredient is stated as expensive. Wikia state it's so complex that Slughorn boast the inventor can't invent it without Slughorn's help, though I can't find the source right now.

Answer (score 14):

From [the Pottermore Page](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/remus-lupin) for Remus Lupin:

> One development in the wizarding community gave Remus hope: the discovery of the Wolfsbane Potion. While this did not prevent a werewolf losing his human form once a month, it restricted his transformation to that of an ordinary and sleepy wolf.

I think it is safe to assume that Lupin would take his wolfsbane potion regularly and hence, Tonks wouldn't need to worry much about it.

Comment: I think this answer misses one key point that Bellatrix includes in that he "keeps his mind when he transforms". A wolf, ordinary and sleepy or not, seems problematic inside a house.

Comment: @DasBeasto Millions of people keep ordinary sleepy wolves (of the subspecies *Canis lupus familiaris*) in their houses without problems.

Comment: See my comment on Bellatrix's answer. The Wolfsbane Potion is very expensive and it's unlikely that Lupin would've been able to afford it.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Dogs are generally different from "ordinary wolves," having been bred for domestication for centuries.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Regardless of that though, what matters is that mentally he is not a wolf.  His mind stays human, and the only reason for hiding is to avoid scaring members of the public.  Between him and Tonks - I'm not googling at work, but I'd be ***amazed*** if there weren't erotic furry fanfics for what happens during that week...